# IdTcpServer послать первым сообщение клиенту Delphi

Tags: delphi, tcp

Подскажите по нажатию кнопки, какой командой сервер может отправить клиенту сообщение, по TCP

Delphi XE8, Indy 10, IdTcpServer

Comment: Есть сомнение, что сервер может клиенту вообще послать сообщение без инициации им соединения. Прерогатива сервера - отвечать на запросы, а клиента - их отправлять. Если клиент не устанавливал соединение, значит оно ему не надо. Если надо установить соединение, то запускайте еще один серверный сокет на стороне клиента

Answer (score 3, accepted):

где то так

```
IdTCPClient1.Host := '127.0.0.1';
IdTCPClient1.Connect;// подключились
IdTCPClient1.Socket.WriteLn('command'); // отправили команду  command и перевод строки
//Ожидаем ответ и закрываем соединение
txtResults.Lines.Append(IdTCPClient1.Socket.ReadLn);
IdTCPClient1.Disconnect;
```

в данном случае команда - это просто текст с переводом строки. Это сильно упрощает прием команды с другой стороны (просто ReadLn). В общем же случае нужно придумывать (или использовать готовый) протокол.

**upd**

выше это был клиент. А теперь сервер. С сервером все немного сложнее. Понятное дело, что для сервера нормально обслуживать не одного клиента,  многих. И для этого есть несколько "схем".

- Классическая - один клиент - один поток. Схема проста в кодировании, интуитивно понятна. Хорошо распаралеливается по ядрам. Недостаток - обычно очень сложно создать много потоков, а это ограничивает кол-во клиентов. Для 32битных программ верхний предел где то в районе 1500 (полторы тысячи) потоков на процесс. Но в этом случае накладные расходы на их переключение могут "скушать" весь проц. Именно  эта схема используется в indy.
- Вторая классическая - все клиенты на один поток. Эта схема часто более сложна в кодировании, но при правильном подходе позволяет держать 20-30к "медленных пользователей" практически не нагружая ядро. Сильный плюс этой схемы - можно обойтись без мютексов и других примитивов синхронизации. Эту схему использует NodeJS и стандартные классы для работы с сетью в Qt.
- Смешанная. В этом случае создается несколько потоков, каждый с которых обслуживает какое-то кол-во клиентов. Самая сложная в кодировании, но позволяет по максимуму использовать ресурсы железа.

Как это сделано в Indy. Indy tcp сервер для каждого подключения создает отдельный поток (TThread) и дальнейшая работа с клиентом идет в нем. Indy красиво это прячет, оставляя для пользователя только необходимость реализовать метод `IdTCPServer.onExecute`.  Но, как я сказал выше, этот метод запускается в отдельном треде и он у каждого клиента свой личный. Это значит следующее:

- в этом методе можно позвать sleep и только один клиент будет ждать. Все остальные будут работать (а вот если в обработчике нажатия кнопки позвать sleep, то результат известен)

  - обращаться к глобальным переменным лучше только через примитивы синхронизации.
  - обращаться к элементам gui нужно аккуратно и правильно. Напрямую лучше не делать (некоторые компоненты разрешают обращаться  к ним с других потоков, но нужно внимательно читать доки).
  - обращаться к другим клиентам нужно через блокировку (потому что если два потока захотят писать одному и тому же пользователю - ничего хорошего с этого не выйдет).

Рассмотрим очень простой пример. На любой запрос клиента отвечаем тем же и закрываем соединение (такой себе echo сервер).

```
procedure TForm1.IdTCPServer1Execute(AContext: TIdContext);
var
  strText: String;
begin
  //Принимаем от клиента строку
  strText := AContext.Connection.Socket.ReadLn;
  //Отвечаем
  AContext.Connection.Socket.WriteLn(strText);

  //Закрываем соединение с пользователем
  AContext.Connection.Disconnect;
end;
```

`AContext` это специальный объект, который содержит всю необходимую информацию о клиенте. Сам `idTcpServer` содержит список этих контекстов и к нему можно обратиться. Рассмотрим более сложный бродкаст. То есть, разослать одно сообщение всем

```
Var
  Clients : TList;
  i : integer;
begin
  // защита от дурака:)
  if not Assigned(IdTCPServer1.Contexts) then exit;

  // получим список клиентов, и заблокируем его
  Clients:=IdTCPServer1.Contexts.LockList;
  try
    for i := 0 to Clients.Count-1 do
      try
        //LBuffer имеет тип TBytes и содержит подготовленные данные для отправки
        // но можно и WriteLn использовать.
        TIdContext(Clients[i]).Connection.IOHandler.Write(LBuffer);
      except
        // тут нужно добавить логику. Клиент может отключиться в процессе
      end;
  finally
    // важно! список нужно разблокировать, иначе другие методы не смогут пройти дальше Contexts.LockList
    IdTCPServer1.Contexts.UnlockList;
  end;

end;
```

инди содержит BytesToString() и ToBytes() для предобразования String и TIdBytes друг в дружку.

Список блокируется, что бы другие не могли его модифицировать. Иначе сам цикл сильно усложняется. И главное, не забывать разблокировать!

Остался последний вопрос. Как отправить сообщение какому то определенному клиенту. Для этого нужно научиться идентифицировать соединение. Это можно сделать несколькими способами - посмотреть в айпи/порт. Но есть лучше. У IdContext (точнее у его предка idTask) есть свойство Data типа TObject. В него можно записать свой объект и хранить там все нужные данные. Типичный пример использования будет следующий. Когда клиент только подключился - это поле пустое. Когда он прошел проверку имени-пароля - создаем объект (свой), сохраняем имя туда и прописываем в свойство Data. А потом, когда нужно делать цикл по подключенным клиентам, просто вычитываем его. Конечно, если пользователей тысячи, каждый раз просматривать всех пользователей будет накладно. Но как делать это более оптимально - тема другой большой статьи.

Comment: вопрос был про сервер, а не про клиента :)

Comment: Слона то я и не приметил. Утром обновляю ответ

Comment: Если у Вас есть вопросы, пишите их на этом сайте. В Скайпе, если даже я добавлю, я вряд ли буду отвечать.

Comment: я не буду писать движок для сервера на делфи. даже за деньги. Если подобное нужно - пишите на фриланс биржи

Comment: вы не подскажете, как Clients : TList; хранить в базе данных, например mySQL?

Comment: не вижу смысла. Но если очень сильно хочется - в начале onExecute просто добавляем в базу. Как именно там хранить - это уже другой вопрос.

Comment: где добавить это я как раз таки понял, а в базу как добавить нет. я не пойму как, какой тип это добавлять, там же может быть все что угодно в TLists. например в Мемо вывести содержимое как? Нужно создать новую тему?

Comment: смысл что б потом идентифицировать, адрес tcp с именем клиента

Comment: создавайте новый вопрос и точно напишите, что Вы хотите.

Comment: подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно идентифицировать эти подключения? Как понять под каким индексом находится клиент по имени Вася, если имя указывается только при подключении(первое сообщение), а ответ мне нужно присылать, намного позже и в промежутке этого времени, может подсоединиться и отсоединиться некоторое количество клиентов

Comment: в последнем абзаце ответа есть вся необходимая информация

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57843/discussion-between-artgrek13-and-kovadim).